# Azure policy to deny assigning any of the existing custom roles to users

Tags: azure, rbac, azure-policy, azure-rbac, azure-security

As a part of Azure Governance, I want to deny all the members(owners) from assigning an existing custom role to any user at subscription or resource group level. I'm wondering it is even possible. If so, what would be the policy?

I achieved a policy to deny custom role creation and seen the same here([Azure Policy not denying Custom Role creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54542727/azure-policy-not-denying-custom-role-creation)). However, my requirement would be something like an add-on to this.

Answer (score 0):

**I Tried to reproduce the same in my environment to Block Custom Role access to Azure AD users:**

I created custom role, like below.

**Azure Portal > Subscription > Your Subscription > Access control (IAM) > Add> Add Custom Role:**

[image]

**Created Custom Role.**

[image]

**Create the policy to block assigning access to Azure AD user.**

**Azure Portal > Azure Policy > Definitions >Policy Definitions>**

[image]

**Policy code:**

Add your custom redefinition ID to block only custom roles.

```
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/roleDefinitionId",
          "contains": "XXXXXX-29dd-4688-8c34-9d035095c507"
        },
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments"
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "deny"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {}
}
```

Assign policy to Scope Level, like below.

**Azure Policy > Definition > Select your policy > Assign**

[image]

If I tried to assign the **Custom** role on Subscription Level, getting below error, if user have **Owner** Role.

[image]

User have **Owner** role access on **Subscription**

[image]

Reference: [Azure custom role: authorize role assignment for a specific set of roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59270885/azure-custom-role-authorize-role-assignment-for-a-specific-set-of-roles) : Followed By: user2761155.

Comment: I appreciate your detailed explanation along with screenshots. Thanks a ton!!!

Comment: But let's consider 2 challenges here: 

1. Let's say we have 100's of existing custom roles and we want to deny the users to assign all those custom roles. In this case, it'll become a tedious task to include all the existing custom role definition IDs in the policy. 

2. On the other hand, there are high chances for creation of new custom roles which will add on to the existing custom roles, in this scenario, we need to keep on adding new roleDefinition IDs in the policy as they are created. And again, this will be a tedious task.

Need to overcome these two challenges

Comment: I hope you'll find my comment. :)
@VenkatV